# Как должны выглядеть тест кейсы с использованием MSTest в С#?

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты, тестирование, mstest

Разъясните, пожалуйста, с примером, что такое тест кейсы на примере модульных тестов MS Test.

История начинается с того, что получил вот такое замечание: *При тестировании следует использовать тест кейсы*

Пример того, как тесты выглядят сейчас(спецом не вставляю тестируемые методы):

```
[DataTestMethod, Description("Testing the properties of the vector lengths. Positive test result.")]
[DynamicData(nameof(GetVectorsWithPositiveNumbersForLengthTest), DynamicDataSourceType.Method)]
public void LengthProperty_OneVector_PositiveTestResult(Vector vector, double expectedLength)
{
    Assert.AreEqual(expectedLength, vector.Length);
}

private static IEnumerable<object[]> GetVectorsWithPositiveNumbersForLengthTest()
{
    yield return new object[] { new Vector(5, 1, 4), 22 };
    yield return new object[] { new Vector(10, 20, 30), 1310 };
    yield return new object[] { new Vector(6, 12, 9), 231 };
}
```

Как будет выглядеть следующий пример, если его тестировать через *тест кейсы*? Спасибо.

Comment: В MSTest используется [DataRow](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.datarowattribute?view=mstest-net-1.2.0)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, а если данные подготавливаются динамически? В _DataRow_ я не могу динамически создать какой-либо объект. А в примере выше как раз используется такая система.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В MSTest для задания тест-кейсов используется атрибут [DataRow](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.datarowattribute?view=mstest-net-1.2.0).
В нём передаются параметры.
Сложный тип - в данном случае Vector - создаётся внутри тестового метода.

```
[DataTestMethod]
[DataRow(5, 1, 4, 22)]
[DataRow(10, 20, 30, 1310)]
[DataRow(6, 12, 9, 231)]
public void LengthProperty_OneVector_PositiveTestResult(double x, double y, double z, double expectedLength)
{
    var vector = new Vector(x, y, z);

    Assert.AreEqual(expectedLength, vector.Length);
}
```